# Resrouce-ref in web.xml breaks servlet mapping

Tags: web.xml, websphere-7

I am trying to add a resource-ref to my web.xml. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>de.so.orderalloc.servlet.web</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <display-name>OrderAllocServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>OrderAllocServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.OrderAllocServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OrderAllocServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/OrderAllocServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Everything is working as intended. Then I am adding the resource-ref so that it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>de.so.orderalloc.servlet.web</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <display-name>OrderAllocServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>OrderAllocServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.OrderAllocServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OrderAllocServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/OrderAllocServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/as400</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

After that if I submit my form I will get this error:

```
Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /de.so.orderalloc.servlet.web/OrderAllocServlet
```

I can't figure out why it breaks when I add the resource-ref. Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My guess would be that there's some underlying exception that's causing this - can you check your server logs (SystemOut/SystemErr) to see if there's another exception stack somewhere, or perhaps a "caused by..." for the one you posted?

Comment: I couln't find any errors in logs, unfortunately... I appreciate your help! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved.

The problem was that I didn't add a

```
<resource-ref name="jdbc/as400" binding-name="jdbc/as400"></resource-ref>
```

to my ibm-web-bnd-xml.